# Unity VR custom shader material is only rendered in the left eye

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, virtual-reality, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I have a problem in my Unity VR project, where I'm doing a red highlight material created from an Unity Built-in Shader Graph.

However, the material is only rendered in the Left Eye and not in the Right Eye, which makes it look strange when seeing the highlight in VR. How can I make the material appear in both Eyes (left and right)?

I'm using the Built-In pipeline and my Oculus are the Oculus Rift.

Here are two pictures, one from my problem and the other that is how I have my shader graph:

[How the highlight appears in VR, with the material only being rendered in the Left eye](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRodd.png)

[How my shader graph is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McUIt.png)

Edit: Nevermind. I was using a Single Pass Stereo Rendering Mode, and it started being rendered in both eyes as soon as I changed that to Multi Pass Stereo Rendering Mode.